# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1255x944")
photo = PhotoImage(file="photo.png")

lab = Label(image=photo)
lab.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is my code

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itachi/PycharmProjects/GUI_course/gui1_initialize.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```